# @Valid annotation on selected fields only

Tags: spring, forms, validation, model-view-controller

I have an account class where I use notations as follows:

```
@NotNull
private String name;
```

In account there are many fields, which I use independently in two forms. The issue is that as my first form doesn't contain

```
private String name;
```

When I submit the form the validation check fails as a field that isn't in the actual form is being checked.

Essentially the validation will always fail as the variable is in the same class but isn't being used in this particular form.

To get around this would I have to use the Spring Validator class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not overcome this kind of problem while having validation annotations. But you can try these:

- Create two custom classes for two forms and validate name just for one of them, and do not validate for another.
- And also you can try to validate your own field manually in the controller method. Autowire validator class, and validate inside the method.

  ```
  @Autowired
  Validator validator;

  public methodA(Model model, @ModelAttribute("modelA") ModelA modelA, BindingResult result){
      validator.validate(modelA, result);

      if (result.hasErrors()){
        // do something
      }

      else {
        // do something else
      }
  }
  ```